# How to make responsible camera for multiplie resolutions?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I m working and some 2d game for mobile phones relate to chess, and I have a trouble with show board for different resolutions of mobile screens. 
Here u can see how it must be on 9:16 resolution: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MFt-FtEtqkk7QWQC2oAtMBA0WAgOIV4h
And how it looks on smaller screen:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11WLYZwHEa9ijXbekzUbE5ZbjbEnjZ6Lb

How can I protect my chess board from cropping?

Comment: Strongly recommend [Camera Fit](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/camera-fit-screen-handler-57439)

Comment: Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

Answer: it depends on how you want it to look.

If you just want it to fit perfectly horizontally, you need to perform 3 steps:

1. Evaluate the width of the Sprite (with `Sprite.bounds`)
2. Evaluate the width of the current screen (with `Screen.width` and using the main Camera)
3. Scale the Sprite to fit the screen

If you are using UI elements, you can do the same thing but you won't need to use Camera, just scaling according to the Screen width (look for `RectTransform.deltaSize` to give you the size of a UI element).

If you are using UI, also consider using [layout groups](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIAutoLayout.html), they help you with fitting the content to screen size.

Anyway, in a device with small width, maybe the table will get too small and you might have to think about better options to display the board instead of just scaling with screen width.

Comment: U mean I should do it via code? Can u pls share with me some example?

Comment: are you using ui elements or common gameobjects?